# Does one need to reload PowerDNS after editing the conf file?

Tags: powerdns

I edited the PowerDNS conf file, and added another IP address in the `allow-axfr-ips=` section, but that IP address is still not allowed to do anything. I checked the firewall, that is also not interfering.

So, my question is do I need to reload, and or restart the `pdns_server` binary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to reload the service if you change configuration. Most if not all services do not actively monitor changes to configuration files to see if they have changed.